# How to store data better in php

Tags: php

i'm trying to learn OOP approach in PHP and trying to do everything with classes. In my code i have a simple user login register and profile pages (Will add some details after i feel improved). In profile page user should see and edit his info. So here is my design about my problem

```
<?php
class Profile{
    private attr1;
    private attr2;
    ...

    constructor(){
        /*gets info from db*/
    }

    getters/setters

    function display(){
        /*Displays info to screen*/
    }

    function changeInfo(){
        /*Will change the attribute and update db*/
    }
}
?>
```

Now my problem is about displaying info. I have 2 approaces in mind:

1- Should I store the user's attributes in session and make the class attributes to static to reduce select queries and only use update queries in changeInfo function which will also update the session's values.

2- Should I not care about the number of queries and only use session as a control to check which user is currently viewing.

Which approach is better, and can you explain why?

Comment: Please have a look over here: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and while you're at it, also over here: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As of right now, there's no actual problem to be solved. You're asking advise on how to improve it. Such questions fit better on: [Stack Exchange: Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There usually no "best" way to do a specific task in programming as they can be done in a number of ways. Any answer would likely be opinion based. I will say though, that typically with "best practices" (and these are my rules, not a general standard) that static is usually to be avoided. I would lead toward number 2, but I would just save the instance of the class to the session (which can be done if you use a class autoload function or include the class before session_start).

Comment: If you save all the user's info into the session and don't query the db anymore, what happens if you delete or disable a user while they're logged in and the session timeout isn't for another hour? Something to think about. But depends on how your application works and what its for.

Comment: @icecub sorry i thought the performance questions count as appropriate questions thanks for introducing a better exchange for it

Comment: No need to appologise. Everyone makes mistakes, especially when you haven't been a member for so long. No one will hold a grudge against you for that.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn why should i store data that won't be used to session if i should go for second approach? Isn't it contradicting to OOP design principles as it would be the responsibility to store the data for user

Comment: @developerwjk thanks for reminding me an important case to write, but i think i can handle it as when disabling a user i'd destroy it's session

Comment: The difference between querying the database and storing in session is really just a preference (typically based on design of your server). On one hand, you go to the database, query data (which takes processing) but you only get the fields you need and need to make several requests if you need more data. On the other, you read from disk, unserialize (which would take less processing) but you usually end up storing more than you need but already have everything you need in memory. It is up to you as the developer to decide which is the better tradeoff.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thanks for enlightening me i think it's the most correct answer for this spesific question, would you mind writing it for an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between querying the database and storing in session is really just a preference (typically based on design of your server).

On one hand, you go to the database and query data (which takes processing plus transferring data between processes or network). You only get the fields you need, but you need to make several requests for more data.

On the other side with sessions, you read the session file from disk. That is unserialized into memory which would take less processing but you usually end up storing more than you need. As a result, you already have everything you need in memory.

It is up to you as the developer to decide which is the better tradeoff.